# ServiceStack.Text serialize circular references

Tags: c#, json.net, servicestack, circular-reference

I need to serialize an object graph like this:

```
public class A
{
     public B Link1 {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
     public A Link2 {get;set;}
}
```

So that the json only gets two instances, but is deserialized correctly again. E.g. using a meta Id or something similiar.

I know that there is a way in Json.NET as described here: http://note.harajuku-tech.org/serializing-circular-references-with-jsonnet with meta ids.

Is there a similiar feature in `ServiceStack.Text` Json Serializer?

Otherwise, is it possible to use Json.NET in `ServiceStack` and how?

**EDIT:**

To make it clear, i ask for instance references, not just the same type.
An example of this may be:

```
[
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "BroId": 0,
        "Name": "John",
        "Bros": [
            {
                "$id": "2",
                "BroId": 0,
                "Name": "Jared",
                "Bros": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "$ref": "2"
    }
]
```

There are only 2 objects "really" serialized, the rest is reused using the `$ref` property field. 
Think of an object model having a collection of subitems. These subitems have a back-reference to their parent object. E.G. Customer/Order. One customer has multiple orders, each order has a reference to its customer. 
Now think of what happens, if you serialize one customer.

```
Customer
 -> Order
  -> Customer
   -> Order
    -> ...
```

And you result in something similiar to this site's name. ;)

I really like ServiceStack for its clearity, not to require `KnownTypeAttribute`s etc.

I would love to keep it that clean, without to implement custom loader/object initializers in my business logic pocos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by an alternative way. **This actually works, but it could make problems later when using more complex data structures with multiple circular references.** But for now there is no need.

I tried in adding the circular references feature to `ServiceStack.Text` but found no point to start at it. Maybe mythz could give me a hint? The feature should be really simple to be done.

I needed that feature for serialization of my data model to fully support `NHibernate`'s merge function.

I followed mythz suggestion to just ignore the properties with the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` which cause the circular references.
But this also requires to rebuild them after deserialization again, to get the merge feature working.

**-> This is the solution, now follows how i did it:**

I started with a simple prototype to test this, a data model of

`Customer` **1->n** `Orders` **1->n** `OrderDetail`.

Each class derives from the entity class.

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order : Entity
{
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail : Entity
{
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual int Amount { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Order Order{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `Order` and `OrderDetail` have a back reference to it's parent objects, which caused the circular references when serialized. This can be fixed by ignoring the back reference with the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`.

My assumption now is, that every child instance of `Order` which is inside `Customer`'s  list property `Orders` has a back reference to this `Customer` instance.

So this is how i rebuild the circular tree:

```
public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateChildReferences(this object input)
    {
        var hashDictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();
        hashDictionary.Add(input.GetHashCode(), input);

        var props = input.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
            {

                var instanceTypesInList = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
                if(instanceTypesInList.Length != 1)
                    continue;

                if (instanceTypesInList[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity)))
                {
                    var list = (IList)propertyInfo.GetValue(input, null);
                    foreach (object t in list)
                    {
                        UpdateReferenceToParent(input, t);
                        UpdateChildReferences(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateReferenceToParent(object parent, object item)
    {
        var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
        var result = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == parent.GetType());

        if (result != null)
            result.SetValue(item, parent, null);
    }
}
```

This code does not work for **1->1** entity references for now (no need yet) but i assume it could be easily extended.

This now allows me to have a POCO class model at client, add/update/remove child objects and send the whole tree back to the server. `Nhibernate` is clever enough to determine, which entity is new/updated/removed. It also only updates the changed entity and only the changed property as well! It also removes all OrderDetails if an Order is removed.

Thats the fluent nhibernate mapping for completeness:

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Schema("YOURSCHEMA");
        Table("CUSTOMER");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAM");
        Map(x => x.City, "CITY");
        HasMany(x => x.Orders)
            .KeyColumn("CUSTOMER_ID")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();


        DynamicUpdate();
    }
}

public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Schema("YOURSCHEMA");
        Table("CUSTOMER_ORDER");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.OrderDate, "ORDER_DATE");
        HasMany(x => x.OrderDetails)
            .KeyColumn("ORDER_ID")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        References<Customer>(x => x.Customer, "CUSTOMER_ID");
        DynamicUpdate();
    }
}

public class OrderDetailMap : ClassMap<OrderDetail>
{
    public OrderDetailMap()
    {
        Schema("YOURSCHEMA");
        Table("ORDER_DETAIL");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.ProductName, "PRODUCT_NAME");
        Map(x => x.Amount, "AMOUNT");

        References<Order>(x => x.Order, "ORDER_ID");
        DynamicUpdate();
    }
}
```

DynamicUpdate() is used to let nhibernate only update the changed properties.
You now only need to use the `ISession.Merge(customer)` function to save everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to be able to serialize object graphs with cycles, JSON.NET does support it:

```
new JsonSerializer
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack supports circular references by default.

Why not try this yourself first to verify if there's an actual issue before posting? This would take less effort than creating a new question and asking someone else to do it.

Following your example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public B Link1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A Link2 { get; set; }
}

var dto = new A { 
   Name = "A1", 
   Link1 = new B { Name = "B1", Link2 = new A { Name = "A2" } } 
};
dto.ToJson().Print();
```

Will print the JSON string:

```
{"Name":"A1","Link1":{"Name":"B1","Link2":{"Name":"A2"}}}
```

Whilst serializing it to JSON and deserializing it back again like:

```
var fromJson = dto.ToJson().FromJson<A>();
fromJson.PrintDump();
```

Will dump the contents:

```
{
    Name: A1,
    Link1: 
    {
        Name: B1,
        Link2: 
        {
            Name: A2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example dto is not using circular references - it is using different objects for each link property.

Comment: :-) Agree. But that's what I think OP was asking.

Comment: Yes, that was what i was asking for.